# button not opening new activity

Tags: java, android

I've created 3 buttons. Each should open up different activities. I've tested it on my device and it never opens a new activity. Could it be due to the main.xml file where I've used the onClick feature for the button despite no using it within my main activity.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button playButton, rulesButton, aboutButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//when the app starts this method is run
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the layout for fragment_layout.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    rulesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_rules);
    rulesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    aboutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_about);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}



public void buttonPlayClick(){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.will.sata.openGLActivity"));
}

public void buttonRulesClick(){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.will.sata.DetailsActivity"));
}

public void buttonAboutClick(){
    startActivity(new Intent(""));
}
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button_play:
                buttonPlayClick();
                break;
            case R.id.button_about:
                buttonAboutClick();
                break;
            case R.id.button_rules:
                buttonRulesClick();
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.will.sata.DetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.will.sata.openGLActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

main.layout.xml

```
android:id="@+id/button_play"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play"
    android:onClick="PlayGame"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:focusable="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some corrections of your code, I hope it helps:

In main_layout.xml you don't need `android:onClick="playGame"` because you are using `View.OnClickListener` in the main class.

You can also use the `android:onClick="playGame"`, but your code in the Main.class would be like this:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private Button playButton, rulesButton, aboutButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
    rulesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_rules);
    aboutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_about);
}

public void playGame(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button_play:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, OpenGLActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button_rules:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }

}
```

To register a new activity in AndroidManifest.xml you just need to do this

```
<activity android:name="com.example.will.sata.OpenGLActivity"/>
<activity android:name="com.example.will.sata.DetailsActivity"/>`
```

To start a new activity from Main.class you have to do this (It is really important to register the Activity first in the AndroidManifest.xml):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, OpenGLActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, DetailsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Tip: be careful with the naming conventions

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. When I ran it on my device it didn't work but it was fine on emulator (api 21). Is there anyway of getting this code to work for android jellybean 4.2.2 (api 18)?

Comment: Never mind I fixed it by changing 'uses-sdk' in androidManifest